# Prometheus exporters aggregation rule (time period precision)

Tags: prometheus

As I understand ideology of prometheus to aggregate on client side, but it's unclear for me in which interval exporters collect/aggregate metrics?

https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#scheduling

> Metrics should only be pulled from the application when Prometheus scrapes them, exporters should not perform scrapes based on their own timers.

https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/29ac809e484016f721f59ab3bf42a68bf4b0858c/collector/cpu_linux.go#L87

How often exporters run "Update" before server scrape */metrics page?

Answer (score 0):

As that page says, that exporters runs `Update` as part of serving the /metrics page.

Comment: It means that exporter start collecting cpu/ram/etc only when we open /metrics (no any aggregation in backgound), right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.